# Find $ \int_C (2xy^3+\cos x)\,dx + (3x^2y^2+5x)\,dy $ where $C$ is $x^2+y^2=64$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, line-integrals

I want to evaluate the line integral $$ \int_C (2xy^3+\cos x)\,dx + (3x^2y^2+5x)\,dy  $$ where $C$ is the circle $x^2+y^2=64$

I parametrized the circle by $r(t)=8\cos t \ \hat{i} +8\sin t \ \hat{j}$ for $0≤t≤2\pi$ but not sure what to do next

Comment: Replace $x$ and $y$ for the new expressions in terms of $t$ to obtain the new integrand, and multiply it by $ds=\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} dt$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $2xy^3 \ dx$ and $3x^2y^2 \ dy$ look suspiciously similar; in fact they can be written as parts of an exact differential of $x^2y^3$. Likewise for $\cos x \ dx = \cos x \ dx + 0 \ dy$.

In other words, if $f(x,y) = x^2 y^3 + \sin x \ $ then $df = (2xy^3 + \cos x)\ dx + 3x^2y^3 \ dy \ $ and hence

$$\int_C (2xy^3 + \cos x)\ dx + 3x^2y^3 \ dy = 0$$

for any closed path $C$.

So your integral simplifies significantly

$$\int_C  (2xy^3 + \cos x)\ dx + (3x^2y^3 + 5x) \ dy = \int_C 5x \ dy$$

To evaluate $\displaystyle \int_C 5x \ dy \ $, you can use the substitutions you originally proposed. Note that the orientation of the circle matters, so double check the original question for whether or not you are supposed to go clockwise or anticlockwise.

Comment: Thanks! So if anticlockwise?

Comment: Your original parameterization moves around the circle anticlockwise.

Comment: Would 320pi be correct?

Comment: Looks good to me, as that last integral is equal to

$$\int_0^{2\pi} 5 \cdot 8^2 \cdot \cos^2 t \ dt = 320 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2\pi  = 320\pi$$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer(s), you should "upvote" any and all that are helpful by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer. If one answer strikes you as "best" you can "accept" that answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Green theorem, which says

> $$\int_{\partial D}Pdx+Qdy =\int_D \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dxdy.$$

Thus
\begin{align}
\int_C (2xy^3+\cos x)dx + (3x^2y^2+5x)dy &= \int_B (6xy^2+5-6xy^2)dxdy\\
&=\int_0^8\int_0^{2\pi} 5r dr d\theta\\
&=\frac{5\cdot 8^2}{2}\cdot 2\pi\\
&=320\pi,
\end{align}
where $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\le 8^2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

which stops you? I suppose if you notice 
$$
\int_{C} \cos x dx=0,
$$
the rest would be easier.